# docker-compose couchdb missing files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, couchdb

I'm trying to run couchdb via docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:     
  couchdb:
    image: "couchdb:2"
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 5984:5984
    volumes: 
      - /data/couchdb:/opt/couchdb/etc/
      - /data/couchdb_config:/opt/couchdb/etc/local.d
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=myuser
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

the container crashes during start:

Failed to open arguments file "/opt/couchdb/bin/../etc/vm.args": No such file or directory
Usage: erl......
grep: /opt/couchdb/etc/default.d/*.ini: No such file or directory

In data/couchdb_config I am providing a standard local.ini file. When I don't do that, couchdb complains that it's missing as well.

What's the problem here?

Comment: is your data folder with the couchconfig file in the same as docker-compose?

Comment: it's a subfolder
dockercomposefolder/couchdb

Comment: when i remove the "volumes" part, it works. So it's that. But what could be wrong about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was the mapping of a wrong volume:

```
my_couchdb_data:/opt/couchdb/etc
```

should be

```
my_couchdb_data:/opt/couchdb/data
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set points before data path .Docker-comose need to know that data is in the same path as the docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:     
  couchdb:
    image: "couchdb:2"
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 5984:5984
    volumes: 
      - ./data/couchdb:/opt/couchdb/etc/
      - ./data/couchdb_config:/opt/couchdb/etc/local.d
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=myuser
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. In my file, i was using absolute paths, so that's not it...